# How could i type in text input in a website with javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, server

I have a website with 7 input text and a user write in theirs the information in my website and i want that when he click the accepted button, the text saved in the javascript variable came to the text input from the other website.

the other website has 7 input and they are the same than me but i need to write automatically the text from my input in their input.

Do you know how could i make that?
i can pass the javascript variable to a php variable to get it in a SQL server but i need to write the value of that variables that i can get in js, php o sql server in the text input from a website that is not my website.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: i have a website to make form from another websites but when the same format. The thing is that all the websites with that kind of forms have different formats and i want to get the same format for all. For this i want to make a universal format and i need to send the text which is written in my text input to the text input from the others websites.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want just to send a form to another website?
You need to think on cross domain information, maybe you can do it using REST.
But these information are too vague for me.

Comment: yes more or less, i want to send a form. I want to write a form in a website from variables on my website and the click the button "send" or "accept" in the other website when the texts will have finished to type in. All of that make automatically from my website (javascript, html, php or form the sql server)